# Retrieve Data from Firebase and Display in Profile Page - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to Retrieve user data registered on Firebase and display on the user profile page, like this: [image]

However, I don't know if I'm doing it the right way (probably not), since I had problems with ʽfindViewByIDʼ, as I don't know how to use it in a fragment and I ended up adapting it this way:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        
        return view;
```

In the end, when I ran the project, when I clicked to access the profile page, the application crashed before anything even appeared. If possible, could you help me find the error and **make the data actually shown on the page**?

Here are the codes:

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbkg"
    tools:context=".ProfileFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.cardview.CircularRevealCardView
        android:id="@+id/circularRevealCardView"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circular" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/profileImg"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_null"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundedImageViewRounded"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleUsername"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/profileImg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/profileImg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profileImg"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleEmail"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/titleUsername"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/titleUsername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleUsername"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_profilelinear"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleEmail">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followersNo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Seguidores"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/followingNo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/following"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Seguindo"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/user"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Usuário"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/profileUser"
                android:text="username"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/pink"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@color/pinks"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/profileEmail"
                android:text="email"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/pink"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@color/pinks"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Senha"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/profilePassword"
                android:text="password"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/pinks"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/editButton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Editar Perfil"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/pinks"
        app:cornerRadius = "20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ProfileFragment**

```
package com.ete.smarthub;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView profileUsername, profileEmail, profilePassword;
    TextView titleUsername, titleEmail;
    ImageView profileImg;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();


        updateNavHeader();
        return view;

    }

    private void updateNavHeader() {
        profileUsername = getView().findViewById(R.id.profileUser);
        profileEmail = getView().findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profilePassword = getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePassword);
        profileImg = getView().findViewById(R.id.profileImg);

        titleEmail.setText(currentUser.getEmail());
        titleUsername.setText(currentUser.getDisplayName());

        Glide.with(this).load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(profileImg);
    }
}
```

**FormLogin**

```
package com.ete.smarthub;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class FormLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText loginEmail;
    EditText loginPassword;
    TextView signupText, forgetTextLink;
    Button loginButton;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user != null) {

            startActivity(new Intent(FormLogin.this, Drawer.class));
            finish();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loginEmail = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        loginPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        signupText = findViewById(R.id.signupText);
        forgetTextLink = findViewById(R.id.forgetText);



        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String Email = loginEmail.getText().toString();
                String Senha = loginPassword.getText().toString();

            if (!Email.isEmpty() && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(Email).matches()){
                if (!Senha.isEmpty()){
                    fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Senha)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                    Toast.makeText(FormLogin.this, "Login Efetuado!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(FormLogin.this, Drawer.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(FormLogin.this, "Login Falhou!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                    }
                else{
                    loginPassword.setError("Preencha todos os campos!");
                }
                }else if (Email.isEmpty()){
                    loginEmail.setError("Preencha todos os campos!");
                }else {
                    loginEmail.setError("Informe um Email válido");
                }
            }
            });

            forgetTextLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final EditText resetMail = new EditText(v.getContext());
                    final AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Redefinir Senha?");
                    passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Para redefinir sua senha, informe o e-mail" +
                            " cadastrado na sua conta e lhe enviaremos um link com as instruções.");
                    passwordResetDialog.setView(resetMail);

                    passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Enviar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // extract the email and send reset link
                            String mail = resetMail.getText().toString();
                            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(mail).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(FormLogin.this, "Link de redefinição enviado para o e-mail informado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(FormLogin.this, "Erro! Link de redefinição não enviado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("Fechar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // close the dialog
                        }
                    });

                    passwordResetDialog.create().show();
                }
            });
        signupText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FormLogin.this, FormCadastro.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        };
    });
}
}
```

**Log Cat:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.ete.smarthub, PID: 3812
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
> at com.ete.smarthub.ProfileFragment.updateNavHeader(ProfileFragment.java:40)
> at com.ete.smarthub.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:34)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Comment: Please add crash log from the logcat window of your Android Studio

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500** (five hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides that, if the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @PawanHarariya added Crash log.

Comment: Move `updateNavHeader` from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated` (so there is actually a root view). See also [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find reference to the views in a fragment, use the parent view. `getView()` returns the parent view after `onCreateView()` and since you are calling `updateNavHeader()` inside the `onCreateView()` its getting null.

So, either you can initialize all your view in the `onCreate()` itself or make the `view` global so that you can access it anywhere.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       
        // you can also make this global if you don't want to initialize your views in onCreate 
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        // get all your view inside the onCreate itself since you have declared them globally
        profileUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.profileUser);
        profileEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        profilePassword = view.findViewById(R.id.profilePassword);
        profileImg = view.findViewById(R.id.profileImg);

        // These two are missing from your code
        titleEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.titleEmail);
        titleUsername = view.findViewById(R.id.titleUsername);

        updateNavHeader(); // crashing because it called and there is no parent
        return view; // here the parent is returned 

    }

    private void updateNavHeader() {
        
        
        titleEmail.setText(currentUser.getEmail());
        titleUsername.setText(currentUser.getDisplayName());
        Glide.with(this).load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(profileImg);
    }
```

Comment: I followed the instructions and copied the code exactly as you put it. However, in the fragment_profile.xml, only “titleUsername“ and “titleEmail“ were updated. How do I update the others?

Comment: I mean, the password

Comment: You shouldn't display the password. It is not advisable. Moreover that a different question that isn't related to the crash.

Comment: If the answer helped you resolve the crash you can mark it as accepted.